# Testing for empty or nil-value string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set a variable conditionally in Ruby.  I need to set it if the variable is nil or empty (0 length string).  I've come up with the following:

```
variable = id if variable.nil? || (!variable.nil? && variable.empty?)
```

While it works, it doesn't seem very Ruby-like to me.  Is the a more succinct way of expressing the above?

Comment: The "Ruby way" would be to not get into a state where you have a mixture of nils and empty strings. If whatever function is returning this data can return an "empty" value, it should be returning `nil`, not `""`.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The second clause does not need a `!variable.nil?` check—if evaluation reaches that point, `variable.nil` is guaranteed to be false (because of [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)).

This should be sufficient:

```
variable = id if variable.nil? || variable.empty?
```

---

If you're working with Ruby on Rails, [`Object.blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) solves this exact problem:

> An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, `""`, `" "`, `nil`, `[]`, and `{}` are all blank.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed (`Object.blank`).  Ruby and Rails always amazes me with it's zen like simplicities.  Thanks! :)

Comment: This solution wouldn't work for `variable = 3
p variable = 5 if variable.nil? || variable.empty?`

Comment: This assumes @RichardBrown doesn't accidentally put an integer in what he expects to be a string variable, yes.

Comment: Nope, it's a string property of an ActiveRecord object.  I should have specified that, sorry.

Comment: If you're not in Rails, you can cherry-pick the [activesupport](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) gem directly for Object.blank?.

Comment: If you don't put the `?` you'll get a strange error saying something like `no such method String::empty`

Answer (score 79):

If you're in Rails, `.blank?` should be the method you are looking for:

```
a = nil
b = []
c = ""

a.blank? #=> true
b.blank? #=> true
c.blank? #=> true

d = "1"
e = ["1"]

d.blank? #=> false
e.blank? #=> false
```

So the answer would be:

```
variable = id if variable.blank?
```

Comment: Useful: `"    ".blank? #=> true`

Comment: Caveat: `blank?` does not work for `0`, incase you are looking to handle that as well.

Answer (score 45):

```
variable = id if variable.to_s.empty?
```

Comment: There we go! Works cleanly on both `nil` and `""`. Nice and readable, too!