# What is good if an empty string is truthy?

Tags: ruby, boolean, string

In Ruby, an empty string `""` is truthy with respect to conditionals. And I see many people struggling with this fact. Ruby on Rails's `blank?` is one attempt to overcome this problem. On the other hand, it is not immediately obvious when such specification becomes convenient. Is there any use case where this fact becomes handy, or will there be a theoretical problem if it were otherwise?

Comment: Is there any use case where treating `""` as falsy becomes handy? I consider that much more surprising.

Comment: Anywhere where people would consider using `blank?` would be a use case. There are a lot.

Comment: I think this question is just too broad to be reasonably answered. You are asking why a language design decision has been made. I can provide you with a valid use case where this becomes handy as well as one where it's not.

Comment: I've never seen anybody struggle with the idea that an empty string is truthy, unless they've only ever programmed JavaScript. I think virtually every Ruby program in existence is pretty much a use case for treating strings as truthy. If you want a variable to be semantically empty, you want it to be `nil`. A string is a string is a string, just because it's a zero-length string doesn't change that.

Comment: @Jueecy.new Any design is not perfect. Providing one use case where it is handy can be a good answer.

Comment: @sawa, I will then. Can you provide me with a use case where it's not, first?

Comment: What do you mean "one use case"? Every line of Ruby code where a variable is tested as a conditional is a use case. `x = my_function; puts x if x` where my function returns a string or false. Done.

Comment: @Jueecy.new http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988960

Comment: It's certainly handy to reduce the number of *falsey* values. Look at the mess PHP is. The less values, the clearer, easier to understand and remember the boolean rules.

Comment: @Sawa I consider that a case where treating empty strings as true is a *good* thing. `blank?` has important semantic meaning. Treating an empty string as `false` just so you don't have to type `.blank?` sounds like a horrible idea. I want `x ||= ""` to work correctly.

Comment: @deceze The mess with PHP may be a hint. If you can make the mess explicit, then that would be a good answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I came up with the answer. Probably, it is for theoretical reason and for efficiency. Drawing a line between different instances of a single class is theoretically more complicated than drawing a line between classes, and would require more computation. If `""` were falesy, then the Ruby internal would have to check the string's length each time there is a string in a condition. Instead, if the truethyness can be judged just by the class, which happens to be the case, then it would be much more efficient. Perhaps this is also the reason why `false` and `true` are not subsumed under a single class `Boolean` but belong to independent classes respectively.

Another possibility is that there are only one instances of `false` and `nil`, so dealing with that internally in Ruby would only require to check the pointer/object id, whereas strings are mutable, and would require more complexity to check for emptyness.

Answer (score 5):

Reducing the number of things that are considered *falsey* is a good thing. It simplifies the language, simplifies the boolean rules, makes them easier to remember and apply and thereby reduces bugs.

Just look at the mess PHP is in: `false`, `0`, `0.0`, `'0'`, `''`, `null` and `array()` are all *falsey*, which keeps surprising many people every day.

If you want to test for an empty string, test for an empty string. You should know whether your variable contains a string or a boolean and be able to test accordingly.

Comment: Your point that the less the better makes sense, but still sounds a little weak. Can you elaborate on what makes it surprising in PHP?

Comment: Well, especially `'0'` (0 as a string) is pretty contentious. It's not an *empty* string, yet it's considered `false`. That seems rather arbitrary. Then why not `'false'` (the string "false")? Because that's a *non-empty string*. So the rule is *non-empty strings except `'0'` are false*. This is a lot harder to explain and retain for newbs than `false` and `nil` are `false`, period. In PHP you have to really think about things like *may this function possibly return an empty array and do I really want this to mean `false`?* Or *may the input here be `"0"` and should this be `false`?*

Comment: But the point here is not about `'false'` or `'0'`. It is about `""`.

Comment: Maybe so, but *my* point is *the less, the better*. Ruby drew the line very close to the minimum possible set of `false` values. It's just adhering to the less is more philosophy as closely as possible. `""` didn't make the cut. Ask Matz for the reason, nobody else can tell you.

Answer (score 2):

I think Ruby was designed to be simple, and having FEWER values that are false makes programs easier to reason about: "Only two objects have a boolean value of false, these are the false object itself and the nil object."

The trade-off is that you may have to write `.blank?` more.  On the other hand, how many fields have a minimum length of one? Not many. If you are checking for `.size > 1` anyway, then "empty string being truthy" isn't useful.

Every language chooses it's "paradigm". For instance, in SQL, Boolean operations actually have 3 values (true, false, null). In Perl and C, `0` is false. Heck, in some languages, the string "false" is false.

Comment: Your answer is kind of too abstract. If fewer is better, then why is there not only one but two falsy elements? Why is two okay and not three?